# Django haystack load_all caching

Tags: memcached, django-haystack

I am trying to optimise my colleagues django haystack search function, there is a queryset.load_all() which loads 200 model instances, now, given I cannot cache the result from load_all(), is there a way to cache those individual model instance so load_all() will read from memcache to get those model instances?

code looks like this

```
result_set = query_set.load_all()[:self.max_results]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in 2 steps:

1. Create a cache manager for your models that caches results.
2. Override index_queryset in your SearchIndex so you can set the manager to use:

> ```
> def index_queryset(self):
>     self.get_model().my_super_cache_manager.all()
> ```